# Alternatives to Yahoo! BOSS

Tags: search-engine

So, for all of my site search/search engine needs, I have been using Google Custom Search. But, recently I've been looking for an alternative that gives me both Image & Web search capabilities. From what I've seen, Yahoo! BOSS fits the ticket almost exactly. The only 2 problems are that it doesn't exist any longer, & it wouldn't have been free even if it still did exist. I tried looking at other posts on Software Recommendations, but there was only one, and it had no responses.

If you have any recommendations, please consider the following:

1. Is it free (or freemium with a reasonable search requests limit)?
2. Does it by default give you access to both web & image search results (or more)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.